# Codecademy lesson troubles

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript through Codecademy, but I have an issue. The code below is supposed to search through the `text` variable for my name in the `myName` variable and then push all of the individual letters to the `hits` array. The code that I have written is not correct but Codecademy says that it is correct and is going to let me move on in the lesson.

I have been trying to solve the issue that I am having with no luck. The problem is that when I run the `hits.push(text);` line it will output the entire variable but I have tried `hits.push(text[i]);` and get undefined for the result. Can someone please help me understand where I have made the mistake?

```
/*jshint multistr:true */
var text = "XsddfasASSFABrandonSFsdfdasBrandonsddfadfaBrandon";
var myName = "Brandon";
var hits = [];
for (i=0; i<=text.length;i++){
    if (text[i]===myName[i]){
        for(var x=i; x<i+myName.length;x++){
            hits.push(text);
        }
    }
}
if (hits.length===0){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to find your whole name intact or just the individual letters in it? Will the result have 3 elements or over 30?

Comment: just the letters I solved it though with the help of @crowjonah' suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think to explain your mistake is simply by walking through a bit of the logic of what you have written.

```
for (i=0; i<=text.length;i++){
```

Your `for` loop will iterate `i` for as many characters as there are in your `text` variable, so: 49 times.

```
if (text[i]===myName[i]){
```

The first run through your `for` loop, where `i=0`, you are checking to see if `text[0]` is strictly equal to `myName[0]`. `text[0] = X` and `myName[0] = B`. The strictly equals condition is not met, so the loop proceeds to increment `i` repeat: `text[1] = s` and `myName[1] = r`. This continues 47 more times, and the condition is never met. `myName[i]` is undefined after the first 7 loops.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would do this kind of thing using `indexOf`, `match`, `search`, `substr` or `substring`, which are all [string methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).

However for the purpose of this exercise you can do:

```
var text = "XsddfasASSFABrandonSFsdfdasBrandonsddfadfaBrandon";
var myName = "Brandon";
var hits = [],
    namePosition = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === myName[namePosition]) {
        hits.push(text[i]);
        namePosition ++;
        if (hits.length === myName.length) {
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        namePosition = 0;
        hits = [];
    }
}
if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
    console.log(hits);
}​
```

(See it working at http://jsfiddle.net/wCWxr/1/). The problems with your original code include:

1. you try to compare `text[i]` to `myName[i]` but the indices of the two strings won't match up.
2. you try to push the entire string `text` into `hits` instead of one character at a time
3. your logic doesn't deal with the possibility that the beginning but not the end of `myName` is in `text`, e.g. if text was aerwerBrasdfsgars

My suggestion fixes this by recording (with `namePosition`) what position we are currently at within the string `myName`, and incrementing that when we find a character in `text` that matches the relevant character in `myName`. If the characters do not match then it's not a true hit, so we reset `hits = []` and `namePosition = 0`. If the characters all match then `hits` eventually reaches the length of `myName` and so we break out of the loop.

Comment: And bearing in mind that `namePosition` is always equal to `hits.length` the above could be simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/wCWxr/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find if myName is in text here is what you do:

RegExp:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(myName);
if (pattern.test(text)){
    console.log(myName);
}else {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
```

indexOf:

```
if (text.indexOf(myName) != -1){
    console.log(myName);
}else {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
```

Comment: I realize there is a much easier way to accomplish the task but in the course they haven't talked about any of the above. They were teaching `if/else` statements and `for` loops and this is how they want the code laid out so is there a way to keep what I have with only a couple minor tweaks to make it work as they intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (text[i]===myName[i]){
```

this line should create an error, because myName[i] is not the first letter of myName.

```
if (text[i]===myName[0]){
```

Change to this line should work.